# Evaluate $ \int_0^3 \frac{x^3}{1-x^4}\, dx. $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate
$$
\int_0^3 \frac{x^3}{1-x^4}\, dx.
$$

I evaluated the integral and got $\left[\dfrac{-\ln(1-x^4)}{4}\right]_0^3$ which ended up diverging. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please check the question.  I do not believe the integral equals $\arctan9$.

Comment: I also agree with David.

Comment: **Hint:** Let $t=1-x^4$.

Comment: I computed the same indefinite integral, $-\frac14\ln(1-x^4),$ and so did Wolfram Alpha. The definite integral from $x=0$ to $x=3$ has a singularity at $x=1$ and appears not to be integrable. Yet another reason to check the question; are you integrating the desired function?

Comment: @DavidK: $\displaystyle\int\dfrac1xdx=\ln|x|$

Comment: @DavidK: Exchange the problematic point with a variable tending towards its value, break the integral up into two parts, using limits, notice how nicely the two trouble-making terms cancel each other out, and, in the end, we are left with the desired result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18650/discussion-between-david-k-and-lucian).

Answer (score 0):

The integral gives up easily to direct attack, but with a little twist.

Use the obvious substitution $u=x^4$:

$$\int_0^3 \frac{x^3}{1-x^4}\, dx=\frac{1}{4} \int_0^{81} \frac{du}{1-u}=$$

Now it makes sense to separate the integral into two parts, so the denominator is positive for each part:

$$=\frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{du}{1-u}-\frac{1}{4} \int_1^{81} \frac{du}{u-1}=$$

Now in the first integral we use the substitution $t=1-u$ and in the second $p=u-1$:

$$=\frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t}-\frac{1}{4} \int_0^{80} \frac{dp}{p}=\frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t}-\frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{dp}{p}-\frac{1}{4} \int_1^{80} \frac{dp}{p}=$$

But the first two divergent integrals just cancel each other out (they are equal), so we are allowed to write:

$$\int_0^3 \frac{x^3}{1-x^4}\, dx=-\frac{1}{4} \int_1^{80} \frac{dp}{p}=-\frac{1}{4} \ln 80=-\frac{1}{4} (\ln 5+4 \ln 2)$$

This is the correct answer (formally). Although Wolfram Alpha writes that the original integral diverges, and the answer we obtained is just [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of the integral.

---

Edit. A little justification for the calcelling the divergent integrals. The problem is at $t \to 0$, thus:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t}=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^1 \frac{dt}{t}$$

In this case the limit doesn't exist.

But for any positive real number $\epsilon>0$ we have formally:

$$\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{dt}{t} \equiv \int_\epsilon^1 \frac{dp}{p}$$

We just renamed the variable after all. Moreover, in our particular example we have $t=-p$. So setting:

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^1 \frac{dt}{t}-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^1 \frac{dp}{p}=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( \int_\epsilon^1 \frac{dt}{t}-\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{dp}{p} \right)=0$$

Makes perfect sense.

But the rigorous justification should involve contour integration in the complex plane.

Comment: The two integrals you cancel are divergent.

Comment: @N.S., yes, I'm aware. This is why the answer is Cauchy principal value of the integral, and not a value in the proper sense

Comment: @Yuiry This is not necessarily true if you get the same expressions after different substitutions. In this case you can argue that the substitutions are basically the same....

Comment: @N.S., thank you. I'm bad at being rigorous, could you elaborate a little, maybe make your own answer? I understand that contour integration is the only rigorous way here